# Enum class only available with -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

So I was trying to learn Enum classes. I copied this piece of code from my book:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  enum class Color
  {
    RED,
    BLUE
  };

  Color color = Color::RED;

  if (color == Color::RED) 
    cout << "The color is red!\n";
  else if (color == Color::BLUE)
    cout << "The color is blue!\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I expect the code to print out "The Color is red!"
However, my compiler gives this error:

```
warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu+11
```

and

```
error:'Color' is not a class or namespace
```

I'm currently using Dev-C++5.11. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please read about MCVEs in the help center.

Comment: What is "Dev-C++11"?

Comment: Dev-C++ is a free IDE for Windows that uses either MinGW or TDM-GCC as underlying compiler.

Comment: sorry can't be more helpful than that I'm new to this.

Comment: How about adding `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu+11` to the compiler arguments?

Comment: @DucNguyen Remove the keyword `class` in enum declaration

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/devcpp/) to enable C++11 support.

1. Navigate to Tools -> Compiler Options
2. Settings tab
3. Code Generation tab
4. Change `Language standard -std` to C++11

Comment: Also, consider trying out a modern IDE such as Visual Studio. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Enum classes are a type of enums added to C++ in 2011. For this reason, you have to say to the compiler that you want to use that version of C++ (-std=c++11). Prior versions of C++, like C++03, hadn't that feature.

Dev-C++ uses internally gcc as compiler (g++ and gcc are synonyms), and probably the internal gcc version used by your Dev-C++ version is gcc 4.8.4 or even older, and at that times, the "default" C++ version was C++03 (03 means 2003). So, you have to inform gcc that your source code is written in C++11 with -std=c++11.

Modern versions of gcc or any other compiler assume by default that you are compiling C++11 code (or even, C++14 code), so, you can add that option to your old compiler or update your IDE to a version using C++11 as default.

Answer (score 0):

In `C++ 5.1`enumerators in the same scope must all be distinct from each other and from other variable names.For example :

```
enum Color1 {
Bronze,
Silver,
Gold
};

enum Color2
{
Silver, //conflicts with Color1’s Silver
Gold,   //conflicts with Color1’s Gold 
};
```

`C++ 11` solves the scoping problem with a new category called scoped enums.Keyword `class` appears between the keyword **enum** and the **enum name**.You are using `C++ 5.1`.Hence edit your code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  enum Color
  {
    RED,
    BLUE
  };

  Color color =RED;

  if (color == RED) 
      cout << "The color is red!\n";
  else if (color == BLUE)
      cout << "The color is blue!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/v42Ihs